# Background HTTP Request/processing that allows aborting

Tags: android, android-volley

I need to make a http request in my main activity and if the request completes while the user is reading the basic info in this activity, I must store the returned info in a variable. However, if the user clicks in a button in this activity, another activity will be opened. This new activity will continue waiting the same request started from main activity, and display the data when it finishes.

I've read about IntentService, however it can't be aborted (am I right?) and the user can ask for new data before the request is completed.

What alternatives do I have?

PS: The request will only work while the app is running.

PS2: I'm using Volley for http requests.﻿

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want to use a Service instead of an IntnetService, since volley will kick off on a separate thread. You can then handle the management of the volley task in that service.

Comment: Do Services run even when the application is not running? If so, can I disable this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html Use a bound service. "A bound service runs only as long as another application component is bound to it."